# How could I get the projection when a property can be null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have this model:

```
public class Document
{
    public long Id;
    public DocumentCategory? Category;

}

public class DocumentCategory
{
    public long Id;
    public string Name;
}
```

I would like to do  this query:

```
private Expression<Func<Document, Document>> GetProjeciton()
{
    return x => new Document
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Category = new DocumentCategory()
        {
            Id = x.Category.Id,
            Name = x.Category.Name,
        }
    };
}


return await _context.Documents
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(GetProjeciton())
    .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
    .ToListAsync();
```

But I get an exception: "Nullable object must have a value."

How could set the category in the projection?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `Include()`?

Comment: Well, this is a simple example to show the problem. But I would like to use projection (select()) to get only two properties from DocumentCategory, because the table in the database has more columns that I don't need.

Comment: Is it possible to check if `x.Category` is `null` or not?

Comment: I am not sure. Really the query that is sent to the database is correct, the problem seems to be when EF tries to create the property DocumentCategory.

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does this gain you over just returning the detached entity?

```
return await _context.Documents
    .Include(x => x.Category)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .SingleAsync(x => x.Id == documentId);
```

I am 100% for projection, but I would strongly advise against using the entity class itself as the projection target. The reason that this is a bad idea is that through your code you will have methods that accept an Entity class, however now you will have entities that are actual entities, and entities that are mere projections of an entity. Often these projections cast as entities are incomplete, populating only fields that a particular scenario cares about. This makes it tempting to get into the same troubles as with detached entities, I.e:

```
_context.Attach(projectedEntity);
_context.Entry(projectedEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

... Which will be a mess as soon as you introduce child/relations let alone scenarios where entity properties aren't copied across completely.

If instead your projections are declared as a ViewMOdel or a DTO, then it is crystal clear where methods should be expecting an entity vs. a projection and there is less temptation to get into trouble with attaching. As for the exception itself, you need to handle the fact that the relationship is optional:

```
private Expression<Func<Document, DocumentDto>> GetProjeciton()
{
    return x => new DocumentDto
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Category = x.Category != null
            ? new DocumentCategoryDto()
            {
                Id = x.Category.Id,
                Name = x.Category.Name,
            }
            : null;
    };
}
```

The relationship is optional so before you can provide one to your projection you need to check whether one is available to use as a source.

Edit: On a final note, there are libraries already that can do these projection mappings for you, and allow you to customize the rules around the projections: (I.e. what fields to copy, what to ignore, what to transform etc.) Automapper, Mapster, Mapperly to name a few. Automapper for instance can be set up pretty easily to handle projections and even deep copies:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Document, DocumentDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<DocumentCategory, DocumentCategoryDto>();
};
```

By default Automapper determines the mapping rules based on the destination type, and follows some conventions to automatically support flattening etc., but you can customize field behaviour by adding `.ForMember` to handle specific fields in the destination.

Then to run the projection:

```
return await _context.Documents
    .Where(x => x.Id == documentId)
    .ProjectTo<Document>(config)
    .Single();
```

This compiles down to the SQL to only return the requested data.

Answer (score 0):

As progman suggsted, there is a way to check if it is null or not. This is the way:

```
private Expression<Func<Document, Document>> GetProjeciton()
{
    return x => new Document
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Category = x.Category == null ? null : new DocumentCategory()
        {
            Id = x.Category.Id,
            Name = x.Category.Name,
        }
    };
}


return await _context.Documents
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(GetProjeciton())
    .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
    .ToListAsync();
```

By the moment I will follow his solution, instead to create a class only for projection.

The reason that I prefer to use the same class for different projections it is because in the client side, it is needed in some cases few properties and in another cases some more properties.

For example, I want to search for documents which author is X. I have a datagrid in which I show the list of book only showing the title and the publish year. Another data but the moment I don't want it.

if the user click over a book in this datagrid, then I will show more details, show I will search for the number of pages, image of cover and so on.

If I would have one class for projection, I would need two classes for projection, one for the search and another for the details. I guess it can be confuse for the client application to have so many classes. I prefer only one DTO for all.

Perhaps my idea is wrong, sure, but I am exploring new things, so it is good to have alternatives and use cases in which it is good option.

Thanks.